# Google Fonts API CORS issue on subdomains with underscore

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, google-font-api

I've been using Google Fonts API for a while. I just do a GET call by AJAX to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=MYKEY
```

and I receive a JSON object with all the fonts they have.

The problem comes when I'm trying to do this call from a subdomain with an underscore on it:

```
mysubdomain_something.domain.com
```

I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=MYKEY. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://mysubdomain_something.domain.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

If I do it in a subdomain without an underscore on it, it works just perfect.

Any solution for this problem??

Thanks a lot

Comment: check the network tab in the browser developer tools to see what headers google is sending you on your request

Comment: thanks for your answer :) https://puu.sh/w7evG/dea5617b40.png those are the response headers!